# Simultaneous order, row-filter and column-select with data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to do multiple steps in one line in R to select a value from a data.table (dt) with multiple criteria.

For example:

```
set.seed(123)
dt <- data.table(id = rep(letters[1:2],2),
             time = rnorm(4),
             value = rnorm(4)*100)

#    id        time      value
# 1:  a -0.56047565   12.92877
# 2:  b -0.23017749  171.50650
# 3:  a  1.55870831   46.09162
# 4:  b  0.07050839 -126.50612

# Now I want to select the last (maximum time) value from id == "a"
# My pseudo data.table code looks like this

dt[order(time) & id == "a" & .N, value]
# [1] 12.92877 46.09162
```

Instead of getting the two values I want to get only the last value (which has the higher time-value).

If I do it step-by-step it works:

```
dt <- dt[order(time) & id == "a"]
dt[.N, value]
# [1] 46.09162
```

**Bonus:**

How can I order a data.table without copying the data.table: ie

```
dt <- dt[order(time)]
```

without the `<-`. Similar to the `:=`-operator such as in `dt[, new_val := value*2]` which creates the new variable without copying the whole data.table.

Thank you, any idea is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You say that `dt[order(time) & id == "a"]` works, but `order` gives an integer, not a logical and is simply coerced to `TRUE` so this is equivalent to `dt[TRUE & id=="a"]` or `dt[id=="a"]`. Your example is so small that it *looks like* it works here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For you first question, try

```
dt[id == "a", value[which.max(time)]]
## [1] 46.09162
```

For bonus question, try the [`setorder` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29331287/559784) which will order your data in place (you can also order in descending order by adding `-` in front of `time`)

```
setorder(dt, time)
dt
#    id        time      value
# 1:  a -0.56047565   12.92877
# 2:  b -0.23017749  171.50650
# 3:  b  0.07050839 -126.50612
# 4:  a  1.55870831   46.09162
```

Also, if you already ordering your data by time, you could do both - order by reference and select `value` by condition- in single line

```
setorder(dt, time)[id == "a", value[.N]]
```

Answer (score 6):

I know this is an older question, but I'd like to add something. Having a similar problem I stumbled on this question and although David Arenburg's answer does provide a solution to this exact question, I had trouble with it when trying to replace/overwrite values from that filtered and ordered data.table, so here is an alternative way which also lets you apply `<-` calls directly onto the filtered and ordered data.tabe.

**The key is that data.table lets you concatenate several `[]` to each other.**

Example:

```
dt[id=="a", ][order(time), ][length(value), "value"] <- 0
```

This also works for more than one entry, simply provide a suitable vector as replacement value.

Note however that the `.N` which is a list object needs to be replaced with e.g. length of the column because data.table expects an integer at this position in `i` and the column which you want to select in `j` needs to be wrapped by `""`.

I found this to be the more intuitive way and it lets you not only filter the data table, but also manipulate its values without needing to worry about temporary tables.